# Increase the java heap space of a certain app

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have an application that I want to run it and gives it more heap memory. I run my application using this command in terminal:
`home/bin/hadoop jar $pathofjarfile parameter1 parameter2` but I don't know how to allocate more heap memory when running this application? if anyone could please advise.

Comment: Check Xmx and Xms paramaters

Comment: I did, and I updated my bashrc to include this `export JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx16384m
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx16384m` but still a java heap space error appears

Comment: java -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -jar <jarfile> is the way to specify max and min heap size

Comment: values can be anything for example I have specified 256mb as min size and 0124 mb as max heap size

Comment: @NachiketKate can you please apply the modify to my command?

Comment: myapp is `hadoop` by the way :) hope this will help you to assist me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71306/discussion-between-shepherd-and-nachiket-kate).

Comment: Does that matter? I don't think so. Whatever you app is allocating a heap works same way. before starting your app provide Xms and Xmx params. That should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method to increase the heap space is using the `-Xmx<SizeInGigs>g` option to the [JVM command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html).  For example:

```
java -Xmx4g -jar $pathofjarfile parameter1 parameter2
```

Since you have a path to `home/bin/myapp jar` you will either need to modify the script/application launching the JVM to follow suite or ask about the specific application you are using (IE: JBoss, Tomcat, GlassFish, etc).

Comment: and what about `myapp`? . If you could just tell me the steps? for example, I will open terminal then run this `java -Xmx4g -jar $pathofjarfile parameter1 parameter2` ? or what?

Comment: myapp is `hadoop` by the way :) hope this will help you to assist me

Comment: Doh!  Overlooked the tag, sorry!  I'm assuming you are using the standard `hadoop` script you can actually use the environment variable `HADOOP_OPTS`, setting them to `-Xmx4g`, like: `HADOOP_OPTS="-Xmx4g" home/bin/hadoop jar $pathofjarfile parameter1`.